Can artistic depictions of crime (especially violence) be used as evidence?
Many creative mediums are used to depict (purportedly fictional) crimes:

Paintings and other visual art (for the sake of simplicity, excluding photography)
Lyrics, including rap
Poetry
Prose works, such as novels (but excluding anything marketed as nonfiction, like autobiographies)

In court, are these seen as purely creative ventures or could they be used against their creator in any way? I found Massachusetts court suggests rap lyrics can be evidence of murder but that seems to be ongoing and doesn't go into much detail about existing laws or precedent.
I'm also wondering if any factors change the outcome, such as:

Publication date (before vs. after the real-world crime)
Genre (e.g. sci-fi vs. realistic detective thriller)
Level of detail in the work

See also Was Kepler's sci-fi book "Somnium" used as evidence in his mother's witchcraft trial? (currently unanswered).

https://www.rapontrial.org/

Plenty of animation 'art' is used to explain testimony and evidence at trial including expert testimony this also beyond just court cases but also inquiries coroner's inquests and investigatory reports all official venues.

@civitas But that's not created by the defendant nor was it intended to be fiction.

It depends on the specifics
I know of at least one case where a chest tattoo of a murder scene was relevant evidence for the conviction of the murderer. What convinced the jury that it was non-fiction rather than fiction was that it contained details that would only be known to someone who was there at the time and that had not been made public by the police.
So, if your art shows things that only the perpetrator would know, it can be evidence against you at trial.

How about this: "This is my confession, admissible in court: I killed Darnell Simmons for sport" from Key & Peele's "Rapper Confession".

@Parrotmaster Yes, and I am the  President of the United States. Lies are easy

@Parrotmaster artistic creations, by their very definition, have wide leeway regarding their truthfulness. Would a reasonable person think they actually committed murder or that it's just a song about a life of crime? Is Darnell Simmons a real person, acquainted with the artists? Is he dead? And the song stating it's a confession is not admissible per se. It would be hearsay. Though the rapper may be called in for questioning, if other evidence can corroborate the warrant.

https://www.pbs.org/newshour/show/rap-lyrics-used-evidence-court

That tattoo is quite something! (search for photos of "Anthony Garcia tatoo")

@PatrickT As far as I can find out, that tattoo was not evidence in court per se, but lead to an undercover investigation during which the guy boasted about the murder (and was on tape).Come to think of it, if you only have the tattoo, it might be the tattoo artist who had perpetrator's knowledge ...

Oh, that's better. Thanks for the follow-up!

@Parrotmaster people confess to murders they did not commit, all the time, to seek attention, especially in cases of murders which become very famous. This is one of the reasons many details are kept from the general public, as a filter. If the song was for example "I killed Darnell Simmons with a 9mm, by shooting him twice in the belly from twenty feet, then once he fell, shooting him six more times in the chest point-blank and then once in the head", and these details were true and not public knowledge, then the lyrics would be taken much more seriously as evidence.

Generally one has to establish a foundation and relevance.
Thus, you have to show who and when the artistic work was made by and show a logical reason why it would be relevant to the disputed issue of fact in the case (i.e. that this evidence would make guilt more likely or less likely). Indeed, the articulated reason for admitting the evidence could bear on its admissibility. One could rarely introduce the work, for example, to show that the artist had a general propensity for violence, or to show that the artist was a member of an unpopular religious group.
Sometimes, it could be offered as evidence of premeditation or for an absence of mistake or coincidence, if it was made before the crime occurred.
If lyrics written by a criminal defendant frequently used a slang word, but the criminal defendant testified that the defendant didn't know what that word meant, the lyrics could be used to impeach the credibility of the defendant's testimony.
If the crime was vandalism involving graffiti, and the evidence was images of other works of visual art in the same distinctive style of the graffiti with a distinctive "tag" also found in the graffiti at the crime scene, those images could be admissible to show that the defendant was the one who spray painted the graffiti at issue in the case.
Sometimes, the inclusion of details in the work that were present in the real crime, but which were not disclosed to the public at the time that the work was made, and which are so specific that the similarity is unlikely to be a coincidence, can suggest knowledge of the details of the crime. This could be highly relevant if the criminal defendant claims to have no knowledge of the crime.
Prose could be offered as evidence that a verbal statement with particular phases or speech patterns, was a statement of the criminal defendant (or that it was not a statement of the criminal defendant and was instead someone else's statement), when the authorship of that statement is not absolutely clear, particularly, if the criminal defendant's lawyers are arguing that someone else made that statement.
For example, if the criminal defendant consistently used "y'all" in prose, but the person making the statement said "hey you guys!", that would be relevant evidence tending to suggest that the criminal defendant isn't the person who made the statement.
Even if the evidence was admissible, it would be rare that this kind of evidence alone would establish that someone was guilty of the crime, in and of itself. But together with other evidence, and in light of the arguments made by the prosecution and the defense, it could be persuasive to a jury.
